# MUI How to make a child dropdown stretch to fill a table-cell parent element

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, size, display

I have a parent element with a display of table-cell, and a child dropdown element that I want to stretch to fill the available space within the parent element. I've tried setting the child element's width to 100%, or playing with the display/positioning but it's not filling the entire space.

Here's a sandbox of what I'm trying to do:
https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-hermann-b61vwr?file=/src/App.js

as you can see the dropdown size is not the same as the table cell and it looks weird, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the table header cells *have padding* which doesn't work well with your dropdowns. You essentially need to apply a different style to the table cell headers that contain dropdowns.

You may find a more elegant solution with your code but this should help you get started. Now the dropdowns will take the full-width of their cells. Here's [an example](https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-bush-et7d43):

**Cloned from StyledTableCell**:

```
const StyledTableDropdownCell = styled(TableCell)(({ theme }) => ({
  [`&.${tableCellClasses.head}`]: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
    color: theme.palette.common.white,
    borderBottom: 0,
    border: "1px solid black",
    align: "center",
    padding: 0 // <--- No more table header cell padding
  },
  [`&.${tableCellClasses.body}`]: {
    fontSize: 14
  }
}));
```

**table.js**

```
<StyledTableRow>
  {tableHeadData.map(({ label, align, rowSpan, colSpan }, index) => {
    console.log({ label, index });
    if ([0,1].includes(index)) { // <--- this could be done better
      return (
        <StyledTableDropdownCell
          key={index}
          align={align}
          rowSpan={rowSpan}
          colSpan={colSpan}
        >
          {label}
        </StyledTableDropdownCell>
      );
    }
    return (
      <StyledTableCell
        key={index}
        align={align}
        rowSpan={rowSpan}
        colSpan={colSpan}
      >
        {label}
      </StyledTableCell>
    );
  })}
</StyledTableRow>
```